# Unexpected token < in jquery ajax call for PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am having jquery ajax call as follows.

```
$("form.form-signin").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url : "scripts/logincontroller.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType :"json",
            data: {
                username : $form.find("input[name='username']").val(),
                password : $form.find("input[name='password']").val()
            },
            success: function(response){
                $("div.jumbotron div#error_panel").css("display","block");
                var err_msg = '';
                if(response.errors != null){
                    for(i = 0; i<response.errors.length;i++){
                        err_msg += response.errors[i]+"</br>";
                    }
                    $("div.jumbotron div#error_panel div#message").empty().append(err_msg);
                    return;
                }else{
                    $("div.jumbotron div#error_panel div#message").empty().append("ok");
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown){
                alert(errorThrown+status);
              $("div.jumbotron div#error_panel").css("display","block");
            }
        });

    });
```

Now I have following classes.
This class connects to database and returns db object if success, string error otherwise.

```
//DBConfiguration.class.php
namespace db;
class DBC{
    const username = "root";
    const password = "****";
    const host = "localhost";
    const schema = "mydb";

    static function connect(){
        try{
            $dbh = new \PDO('mysql:host='.self::host.';dbname='.self::schema, self::username, self::password, array(
                \PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
            ));
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            return $dbh;
        }catch (\PDOException $e){
            return "Failed to connect to database";
        }

    }
}
```

This class calls the above connect and returns the result.

```
//Authenticator.php
namespace db;
include "DBConfiguration.class.php";

class Authenticator{
    public function isValidUser($username,$password){
        $result = array();
        $dbh = DBC::connect();
        if(is_string($dbh) && $dbh === "Failed to connect to database"){
            $err = array();
            $err[] =  "Oops! Something went wrong. We are working on it";
            $result["errors"] = $err;
        }else{
            $err = array();
            $err[] =  "connected successfully";
            $result["errors"] = $err;
        }
        return $result;

    }
}

//LOGINCONTROLLER.PHP
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
include "db\Authenticator.php";
$authenticator = new \db\Authenticator();
echo json_encode($authenticator ->isValidUser($_POST["username"],$_POST["password"]));
```

When I am intentionally changing the password and could not connect to db I am getting correct error message. But when it is successful (in which case I am returning db object from connect() method), I am getting 'unexpected token <'.

Weird thing is I am able to run the code when I place all these classes in logincontroller.php instead of induvidual namespaces.

Is there any problem with this code?

Comment: Check the response from the AJAX call in your browser's *Network* developer console tab. It should only be JSON. I'd also throw in an `exit;` immediately after `echo json_encode(...);`

Comment: Also, make sure each PHP script starts with `<?php`. I'd also recommend **not** closing the PHP context, ie **don't** each script with `?>`

Comment: Print to consle the html (datatype:html\text. Consle.log(data) etc . and you will see the error.

Comment: This can also occur if you request a page that is 404 or 403. These are html pages, where the first character is a html tag. As explained before, you don't get back the json that the code expects.

Comment: But it is working when it is unable to connect to DB. But when it could successfully connect to DB, as you can see in the question, in this case also I am returning an error array with success message. But I am not getting that message. Moreover, it is entering error call back of jQuery ajax.

Comment: Chrome is showing 200 OK application/json response

Comment: Can you show us what the actual response that the AJAX call gets is in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. The following line is causing the problem.

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

The above line of code must be

```
$dbh->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

As I am calling this from a namespaced class PDO must refer to global PDO class.